# How to use python to create url shortcut on mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, shortcut, shortcut-file

There are answers to the window version. but not mac.

I have searched google but no appropriate result

let say I want to create a shortcut to google.com on desktop, then we could run the python function

```
createShortcut("www.google.com","~/Desktop")
```

what could be the function body?

Comment: I think you can just write a `whatever.url` file as text with the format here: https://superuser.com/a/689444/1161705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a macos .url file inside the function. It is formatted as follows:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://www.yourweb.com/
IconIndex=0
```

Here is a sample implementation:

```
import os

def createShortcut(url, destination):
    # get home directory if ~ in destination
    if '~' in destination:
        destination = destination.replace('~', os.path.expanduser("~"))
    # macos .url file format
    text = '[InternetShortcut]\nURL=https://{}\nIconIndex=0'.format(url)
    # write .url file to destination
    with open(destination + 'my_shortcut.url', 'w') as fw:
        fw.write(text)
    return

createShortcut("www.google.com", '~/Desktop/')
```